# In scala, how to instruct the compiler to realise the equivalence of two abstract types?

Tags: scala, type-inference, dependent-type, path-dependent-type, abstract-type

I have a simple case to test the type inference capability of scala:

```
    trait Super1[S] {

      final type Out = this.type
      final val out: Out = this
    }

    trait Super2[S] extends Super1[S] {

      final type SS = S
    }

    case class A[S](k: S) extends Super2[S] {}

    val a = A("abc")

    implicitly[a.type =:= a.out.type]
    // success

    implicitly[a.Out =:= a.out.Out]
    // success

    implicitly[a.SS =:= a.out.SS]
    implicitly[a.SS <:< a.out.SS]
    implicitly[a.out.SS <:< a.SS]
    // oops
```

The error for the last 4 lines looks like this:

```
[Error] /home/peng/git-spike/scalaspike/common/src/test/scala/com/tribbloids/spike/scala_spike/AbstractType/InferInheritance.scala:28: Cannot prove that a.SS =:= Super2.this.SS.
[Error] /home/peng/git-spike/scalaspike/common/src/test/scala/com/tribbloids/spike/scala_spike/AbstractType/InferInheritance.scala:29: Cannot prove that a.SS <:< Super2.this.SS.
[Error] /home/peng/git-spike/scalaspike/common/src/test/scala/com/tribbloids/spike/scala_spike/AbstractType/InferInheritance.scala:30: Cannot prove that Super2.this.SS <:< a.SS.
three errors found
```

Clearly scala compiler screwed up on these cases: if I move:

```
      final type Out = this.type
      final val out: Out = this
```

to be under `Super2` it will compile successfully. My question is that: why the status quo inference algorithm won't work in this case? and how can I rewrite my code to circumvent this problem of the compiler?

Comment: Note: this works correctly in Dotty.

Comment: this should be reported here: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dmytro Mitin. Good point, will post it there

Comment: done! https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/12046

Answer (score 2):

If `a.SS =:= a.out.SS` then we should be able to use one in place of the other. Is that the case?

No.

```
val x: a.SS = "hello"
val y: a.out.SS = "hello"
```

Compiling this I get:

```
ScalaFiddle.scala:29: error: type mismatch;
 found   : lang.this.String("hello")
 required: Super2.this.SS
    (which expands to)  S
  val y: a.out.SS = "hello"
```

It looks like Scala understands that `a.SS` is really `String`, which isn't surprising.

But clearly `a.out.SS` isn't `String` but rather... `S`.

Strangely this works even though it's clearly wrong:

```
val b = A(1)
implicitly[a.out.SS =:= b.out.SS]
```

If you just define `out` to be of type `this.type` then your code works.

The best I can come up with is that when defining the type of `out`, Scala fails to associate the actual type represented by `S` with `out` and so the type `SS` as viewed through `out` just has the generic type `S`.

The type `Out` does seem to understand the actual type represented by `S`, so this works:

```
implicitly[a.SS =:= a.Out#SS]
implicitly[a.SS <:< a.Out#SS]
implicitly[a.Out#SS <:< a.SS]
```

and this correctly fails to compile:

```
val b = A(1)
implicitly[a.Out#SS =:= b.Out#SS]
```

Comment: I don't really care if it is String, it resolves to `a.out.S` -> `a.this.S` -> `a.S`. Here, I think the consensus is that scala compiler failed on it. I just need to know what kind of algorithm leads to this kind of failure and if there is a circumvention for it

Comment: Can you use the `Out#SS` suggestion?